# Naming the MIT licence

Tags: licensing

What should you call it? Expat, MIT, X11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSI calls it the MIT license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

Answer (score 3):

MIT seems to describe it best since it is the MIT license.